# Trigger; Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: String but was: List<String>

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

```
//trigger code

trigger mailsentcreateaccusindtri on Account (after insert) 
{
    //list<string> mail= new list<string>();
    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert)
    {
          list<string> mail= new list<string>();

        list<user> u=[select id, name, email from user where profile.name = 'system administrator'];
        for(user us: u)
        {
            mail.add(us.email);
        }
        for(account acc: trigger.new){
            messaging.SingleEmailMessage mg= new messaging.singleEmailmessage();

            mg.setToaddress(new string[] {mail});
            mg.setSubject('New account cretaed on '+acc.createddate);
            mg.setPlainTextBody('New account has been created with the name of '+acc.name);

            list<messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages= new list<messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            messages.add(mg);

            messaging.sendEmail(messages);
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: I believe your error is in this line?  mg.setToaddress(new string[] {mail});
If yes, you are creating a new list of string and add on that another list of string. You could change only by mg.setToaddress(mail);

Answer (score 2):

The `mg.setToaddress()` method expects a parameter of type `List<String>` as you already know.

And your `mail` variable is already of type `List<String>`.

So you don't need to insert it inside a new array of type `String`.

The right code is: `mg.setToaddress(mail);`